# how to not allowed spaces in text field

Tags: swift, xcode, namespaces, uitextfield, lowercase

this is my code I want the user name not to have spaces and lowercase 
example (wizkhalifa)

```
    func textField(_ textFieldToChange: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
            if textFieldToChange == username {
                let characterSetNotAllowed = CharacterSet.whitespaces
                if let _ = string.rangeOfCharacter(from:NSCharacterSet.uppercaseLetters) {
                    return false
                }
                if let _ = string.rangeOfCharacter(from: characterSetNotAllowed, options: .caseInsensitive) {
                    return false
                } else {
                    return true
                }
}

 if  UserNameField.text != nil, emailField.text != nil, passwordField.text != nil, rePassword.text != nil && passwordField.text == rePassword.text {
                Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: emailField.text!, password: passwordField.text!, completion: { (user, error) in
                    if error != nil {
                        AlertController.showAlert(self, titel: "Error", message: " Fill all fields \nUser exists  ")
                        return
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check 2 things and you can put that check in the method called when trying to create a user, and/or when the user is typing.

First check, spaces :

```
if let text = UserNameField.text {
    if text.components(separatedBy: " ").count > 1 && text.lowercased() != textField.text {// add your other tests on this line
        // the text is in lowercase without space character and your tests pass
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: emailField.text!, password: passwordField.text!, completion: { (user, error) in
             // check if there is an error
        })
    } else {
        AlertController.showAlert(self, titel: "Error", message: " Fill all fields \nUser exists  ")

}
```

Here is the version for OP with his code :

```
if  UserNameField.text != nil, emailField.text != nil, passwordField.text != nil, rePassword.text != nil && passwordField.text == rePassword.text && UserNameField.text.components(separatedBy: " ").count <= 1 && UserNameField.text.lowercased() == UserNameField.text {
    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: emailField.text!, password: passwordField.text!, completion: { (user, error) in
        if error != nil {
            AlertController.showAlert(self, title: "Error", message: " Fill all fields \nUser exists  ")
            return
        } else {
            // all good
        }
    })
} else {
    AlertController.showAlert(self, title: "Error", message: " Fill all fields \nUser exists  ")
}
```

Comment: sorry can you give me live example please how i can attach those line to one textField

Comment: I edited my answer with your variable name, juste use that code

Comment: thanks but i got this error Binary operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int?' and 'Int'

Comment: and in programing language you can do one thing in different ways like i can do this in one line

Comment: The error you have is due to an optional type, the ? means the value can either be nil or any value of the type defined. You must unwrap it : I edited the code in my answer. You should probably go check tutorials on how to get started developping in swift (like this one by apple https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/), there is also documentation ibooks

Comment: thank you man but i have question i know i disturbed you if i fill all field its shows alert but the firebase pickup the info in save it so if the alert shows (username incorrect) its still saved to the firebase

Comment: I edited my answer, check the code. If your tests pass you call the firebase method, if they don't pass you call the alert. You really should look at basic tutorials about programming, conditional statements are the first step you make in programming, before learning how to use third part libraries and other stuff.

Comment: can anyone put this method in in my code in the top

Comment: answer edited. Please go learn basic development before taking projects like that.

Comment: this project I'm working on will be the next chat app I really want some help and I don't know any developers so if you interested we can contact

Comment: your method is wrong go check it and see for your self

Comment: indeed I did copy & paste my previous code and the conditions were inverted, and a missing closure. it's updated now

Comment: Binary operator '<=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int?' and 'Int'

Comment: Yes, and you should really hire a developer.

Comment: see this website i fount the way to pervert the white spaces

Comment: You implemented an alert for user error cases, and asked for your code to work with no whitespaces, and only lowercases. That's exactly what I gave you as an answer.

Comment: yes but your code has some errors I cant handle cuz I do search for this answer for almost 2 months now and i couldn't find it go test you code if it's give you some errors like this               (Binary operator '<=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int?' and 'Int')    it's your bad, if not it's my problem but I copy and past your code

Comment: that's called unwrapping optional values

Comment: I tried this (!) and this (?) and I still getting errors if you know what it's called why you didn't wright the code in right way man and save as both a lot of time